# ASM EXE program 16bit: Error changing size of memory

Tags: assembly, tasm, 16-bit

I write **EXE** program with **SMALL** model.
I want to load other programs with the help of my program. I read that first of all I must free some memory. I use `DOS 4Ah INT 21h` interrupt. But I have error 7 (control units memory is destroyed) in AX when use it. What I made incorrect?

```
;-------------------MACRO-----------------
println MACRO info
    push ax
    push dx

    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset info
    int 21h

    ;print new line
    mov dl, 10
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h

    mov dl, 13
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h

    pop dx
    pop ax
ENDM
;-----------------end macro----------------

.model small

.stack 100h

.data

initToRunErrorText db "Bad init to run other programs", '$'

myDataEnd db '0'

.code

main:
    mov ax, @data
    mov es, ax
    mov ds, ax

    call initToRun

    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h

;   Result
;       ax = 0 => all is good
;       ax != 0 => we have an error
initToRun PROC
    push ax bx

    mov ah, 4Ah
    mov bx, offset myDataEnd + 100h
    shr bx, 4
    add bx, 2
    int 21h

    jnc initToRunAllGood

    add ax, '0'
    mov dl, al
    mov ah, 06h
    int 21h

    mov ax, 1
    println initToRunErrorText

    jmp initToRunEnd

initToRunAllGood:
    mov ax, 0

initToRunEnd:
    pop bx ax
    ret
ENDP

program_length equ $-main

end main
```

For compile I use TASM 16 bit with DOSBox 0.74

Comment: You forgot to set `es`.

Comment: @Jester mov es, ax - in main

Comment: You don't need to free memory in an `.exe` program. Only a `.com` program reserves all the memory.

Comment: @rkhb Ok, write it as answer, please. Thank you, man

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to free memory in an `.exe`program. Only a `.com` program reserves all memory. It's rather complicated to determine the real last byte of an `.exe` program and to find the segment of the allocated block. BTW: In a `.com` program you must adjust the stack pointer!

As @RossRidge mentions, some linkers (e.g. TLINK) write into the header an information to allocate the maximum memory. This is annoying.

You can modify this header item by using a tool like Microsoft's `exemod` which is contained in the MASM suites (versions < 6). A suite is downloadable [here](http://www.phatcode.net/downloads.php?id=168). The exemod utility can be found in DISK4. Use it like:

```
exemod <exefile> /max 1
```

Another option is to resize the allocated memory inside the program. Make first a simple program `HELLO.EXE` to be executed by a parent program:

```
.MODEL small
.STACK          ; default: 1000h
.DATA
    hello db "Hello world", 13, 10, "$"
.CODE
main PROC
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    mov dx, OFFSET hello
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h
main ENDP
END main
```

Now the parent:

```
.MODEL small

.STACK

.DATA
    hello db "HELLO.EXE", 0

    params label word
        dw 0
        dw OFFSET command_line, SEG command_line
        dw 0ffffh,0ffffh ; fcb1
        dw 0ffffh,0ffffh ; fcb2

    command_line db 0,13

.CODE

free_memory PROC
    mov ax, sp              ; SS:SP -> nearly the end of program
    shr ax, 4
    mov bx, ss
    add bx, ax
    add bx, 2               ; BX = a paragraph beyond program
    mov ax, es              ; ES -> first paragraph of the program (containing PSP)
    sub bx, ax              ; BX = program size in paragraphs
    mov ah, 4ah             ; Resize memory block - http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2936.htm
    int 21h                 ; Call MS-DOS

    ret
free_memory ENDP

execute_hello PROC
    push ds                 ; Save DS
    push es                 ; Save ES

    mov cs:[stk_seg],ss     ; Save stack pointer
    mov cs:[stk_ptr],sp

    mov ax, 4B00h
    mov dx, OFFSET hello
    mov bx, SEG params
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, OFFSET params

    mov ax,4b00h            ; Exec - load and/or execute program - http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2939.htm
    int 21h                 ; Call MS-DOS

    cli                     ; Let no interrupt disturb
    mov ss,cs:[stk_seg]     ; Restore stack pointer
    mov sp,cs:[stk_ptr]
    sti                     ; Allow interrupts

    pop es                  ; Restore ES and DS
    pop ds
    ret

    ; Data for this function in the code segment
    stk_ptr dw 0
    stk_seg dw 0
execute_hello ENDP

main PROC
    mov ax, @data           ; Initialize DS
    mov ds, ax

    call free_memory        ; ES should point to PSP (default)
    call execute_hello

    mov ax, 4C00h           ; Terminate with return code - http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2974.htm
    int 21h                 ; Call MS-DOS
main ENDP

END main
```

The end of the program is determined by the stack pointer. You should therefore be sure that the STACK segment is the last segment in the program. Generate a `.MAP` file with the tlink command line option `/s`. It should look like:

```
 Start  Stop   Length Name               Class

 00000H 0005BH 0005CH _TEXT              CODE
 00060H 00079H 0001AH _DATA              DATA
 00080H 0047FH 00400H STACK              STACK


Detailed map of segments

 0000:0000 005C C=CODE   S=_TEXT          G=(none)   M=INBBC8~1.ASM ACBP=48
 0006:0000 001A C=DATA   S=_DATA          G=DGROUP  M=INBBC8~1.ASM ACBP=48
 0006:0020 0400 C=STACK  S=STACK          G=DGROUP  M=INBBC8~1.ASM ACBP=74

Program entry point at 0000:004C
```

As you can see `STACK` is the last segment listed here.

Now you can run the parent and read what the child (HELLO.EXE) has to tell :-)

Comment: Actually you do need to free memory in an .EXE program created by TLINK because it sets the maximum paragraphs to allocate field in the EXE header to FFFFh, That means MS-DOS will allocate the biggest chunk of memory for it, just like a .COM file. This of course assumes that you need to allocate the memory for something else, like spawning another program, otherwise you wouldn't need to free the memory whether you're using .EXE or .COM file.

Comment: @RossRidge: You're right. I can't find a link to download an utility like `exemod.exe`. Do you know one? I thinkl when I add a paragraph and a link I don't need to delete this answer (too bad about the pretty 15 points).

Comment: @RossRidge Ok, how can I free memory to spawn new program?

Comment: @AJIOB: Please take a look at my adjusted answer.

Comment: Microsoft has another utility for editing MZ EXE headers called EXEHDR, which I think was was more common, but I don't know where you'd get it now without an MSDN Subscription. It wouldn't be too hard to write a program that changed max paragraphs field though.