# I'd like to load an external .exe file, and to either extend it's original code or modify it while it's running

Tags: assembly, exe, masm, x86-16

I'll start off by saying that I'm new to MASM. I did learn C and Python last year, and then C++-OOP during "summer break" (I took an extra course instead of taking a break), but I don't feel like those skills really help me that much with this specific course.

In my home assignments, my professor usually compiles a simple code of his own, and bundles that .exe file so we have to manually run his file, extract an arbitrary value from it, and then make use of that value in our own code. For example, last time all his program asked us for our student ID number, and then gave us some 'unique key' that we had to include in our own program.

Running two seperate executables feel extremely redundant to me, and I really dislike the fact the my programs aren't modular, so I'd would love to get some help with how to properly use the INT21\4AH and INT21\4BH interrupts.

My professor's programs are pretty basic - they always print an instruction that requests the user to enter something, then read that input and immediately give you the output.
So I'm thinking of two ways of tackling this issue:

1. By injecting: load his code without running it, and then to somehow redirect his program's output to a string instead of printing it - and then run it. In C++ this would be extremely easy to do, but I'm not really sure how I could redirect an output in asm.
2. By extending: to let his code run normally, and once his code is done, I extract needed parameters  from their on-screen coordinates (0b800h:[coords]), and then make use of them in my part of the code.

I managed to find a basic code layout for executables, but I'm having issues with the documentation.

1. Do I need to use INT21\1AH when loading .exe files? because although the code uses it - it says that .exe file don't need much space, unlike .com files.
   So how do I know how much space do I need to allocate?
2. What should my parameters be? I couldn't find any examples for that part. I'm not quite sure what's the layout of an executable, and I'm not sure where it's code is going to be stored at.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to control the location of the external code, when to allocate more memory and how to move back and forth from my code to my professor's code.

That's the basic code:

```
.model small
.stack 200h

clr_scr macro
push ax
push bx
mov ah, 15
int 10h
mov ah,0
int 10h
pop bx
pop ax
endm


.data
    filename db 'KEYGEN.EXE',0
    parameters dw 7 dup (0)
    oldSS dw 0
    oldSP dw 0

.code
start:

mov ax, @data
mov dx, ax
clr_scr

shell:
mov bx, randseg
mov ax, es
sub bx, ax
mov ah,4ah
int 21h

mov ax, seg parameters
mov es, ax
mov bx, offset parameters
mov oldSP, sp
mov oldSS, ss
mov dx, offset filename
mov ax, seg filename
mov ds, ax
mov ah, 4bh
mov al, 00h
int 21h



mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
mov ss, keep_ss
mov sp, keep_sp



 mov ax, 0b800h
 mov es, ax 



exit:

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
randseg segment 
randseg ends
end start
```

Comment: Why are you complicating things? `echo yourstudentid | professorsprogram | yourprogram`

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43216077/5801661) if you really want to execute a program.

Comment: Thanks a lot Margaret!